# Save SSMS tabs with timestamp on a daily basis?

Tags: ssms

Is there a way to automate SSMS to automatically save down all current open tabs into a folder with a timestamp?

Whilst I'd like to save every single useful ad-hoc query ever written with a nice understandable name, I often don't have time and this would be rather useful

Ideas?

Comment: By saving all tabs, wouldn't you also save the non-useful queries?  :)

Comment: why would I write queries that were not useful?!

Answer (score 4):

Actually I think that you simply nedd statement logging. Try ssmstoolspack.

In meantime, my add-in [**SSMSBoost**](http://www.ssmsboost.com) does a lot of logging as well: editor contents history, tabs history, execution statements history...

Comment: Yep that stores tab history automatically.